# Javascript : is it possible to get data using twitter api via front-end (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, twitter, redux

I am creating an app and I need to invite Twitter users to my app through API. my question is 
in Twitter is it possible to get follower list using front end (React) or do I need to use back-end like nodejs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following paragraph is no longer valid for Twitter API, please check the @Akshay Vijay Jain's answer.

Yes, you need a backend because when you use API KEY & API SECRET strings of your app in frontend like React, etc. they are will be usable from everyone. I can steal your API Credentials and use your API for my app this is will exploit your API quota, if you use a premium or enterprise API, I can exploit your money.

Answer (score 3):

Jun 2020 Update.

It's **NOT** possible to connect to twitter API from front-end, by any means, because of same-origin policy of browser, I have done extensive research and experimentation

Twitter's response doesn't include `Access-control-allow-origin` header and so browser will discard the response in between actually browser makes a pre-flight request before actual request and response of the pre-flight request dictates browser to not make actual request to Twitter api.

Only solution is to create `cors-enabled` rest apis on your own node server and in handler of that rest API, call twitter api either using `twitter-lite` or `twit` and return the result back to the front-end as response of `cors-enabled` rest API

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, you can, but it’s not recommended. With API quota you better have twitter API responses cached to make your quota last through larger number of requests.